# Tkinter no puede reconocer imágenes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7, python-2.x

Estoy tratando de poner una imagen en una label de una interfaz, pero cuando corro el programa me sale es siguiente error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Familia\Desktop\Archivos programación\Programación\proyecto
> F\prueba tkinter ventana.pyw", line 18, in 
> imagen=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="tec.jpg")   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3377, in **init**
> Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3331, in **init**
> self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options) TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "tec.jpg"

Este es mi códico

```
import Tkinter

ventana= Tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x500")
ventana.title("Pruebas sudoku")
ventana.resizable(0, 0)
ventana.iconbitmap("logo1.ico")

miframe=Tkinter.Frame(ventana)
miframe.pack()
dato=Tkinter.StringVar()
caja1=Tkinter.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato)
caja1.place(x=150, y=10)

ltexto=Tkinter.Label(ventana, text="etiqueta texto", font=18)
ltexto.place(x=50, y=10)

imagen=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="tec.jpg")
limagen=Tkinter.Label(miframe, image = imagen)
limagen.image = imagen
ventana.mainloop()
```

P.D: ya traté de poner la ruta de la imagen, usar otras imágenes y poner la label en la ventana y no en el frame

Estoy usando pthon 2.7

Answer (score 0):

La clase `PhotoImage` de `tkinter`, soporta los formatos: PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG. Si deseas trabajar con otros formatos, pudieras utilizar `Python Imaging Library (PIL)` , que contiene clases que te permiten utilizar alrededor de 30 formatos, convirtiéndolos en objetos compatibles con Tkinter. `PIL` podrías utilizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
imagen = Image.open("tec.jpg")
foto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
limagen=tkinter.Label(miframe, image = foto)
limagen.image = imagen
limagen.pack()
```